# Variables in ADUsers2CSV script

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, export-to-csv

My main goal is to export some info about users from Active Directory to CSV file.
But in my AD, there is also bunch of some service accounts that I don't want to export and I want to use only specific OUs.

So I created CSV file with "list" of these OUs and filenames of exported CSV, looks like:

```
oubase,oucity,filename
OU=_SubCompany1,OU=_City1,filename1.csv
OU=_SubCompany1,OU=_City2,filename2.csv
OU=_SubCompany3,OU=_City1,filename3.csv
```

And my PS script:

```cs
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$adserver = "ad1.domain.com"
$filter = "'(& (msExchMailboxGuid=*) (!sAMAccountName=*_*))'"
$selection = "personalTitle, msDS-PhoneticFirstName, msDS-PhoneticLastName, msDS-PhoneticDepartment, Title, mobile, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, SamAccountName"
$targetpath = "C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\"
$exportfiles = "C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\export_files.csv"

Import-Csv -Path $exportfiles | ForEach-Object {
    $oubase = $_.'oubase'
    $oucity = $_.'oucity'
    $filename = $_.'filename'
    $fullpath = $targetpath + $filename

    $fullbase = "'OU=Users," + $oucity + "," + $oubase + ",DC=domain,DC=com'"
    #$fullbase = 'OU=Users,OU=_City2,OU=_SubCompany1,DC=domain,DC=com'

    Get-ADUser -Server $adserver -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties * -SearchBase $fullbase |
        select $selection |
        Export-Csv -Encoding Unicode $fullpath
```

But the script isn't working. There is some problem with variables in the `Get-ADUser` command.
When I type in directly all the values, everything is working:

```
Get-ADUser -Server ad1.domain.com -LDAPFilter '(& (msExchMailboxGuid=*) (!sAMAccountName=*_*))' -Properties * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=_City2,OU=_SubCompany1,DC=domain,DC=com' |
    select personalTitle, msDS-PhoneticFirstName, msDS-PhoneticLastName, msDS-PhoneticDepartment, Title, mobile, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -Encoding Unicode C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\filename2.csv
```

When I try to display the content of variables, it seems OK, no extra whitespaces or commas etc.

I think variables `$filter` and `$fullbase` are problematic.

When I try it like with `$filter` variable, command won't return any error and it creates empty CSVs:

```
Get-ADUser -Server $adserver -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=_City2,OU=_SubCompany1,DC=domain,DC=com' |
    select personalTitle, msDS-PhoneticFirstName, msDS-PhoneticLastName, msDS-PhoneticDepartment, Title, mobile, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -Encoding Unicode C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\filename2.csv
```

When I try it with `$fullbase` variable, command returns this error.

```
Get-ADUser -Server $adserver -LDAPFilter '(& (msExchMailboxGuid=*) (!sAMAccountName=*_*))' -Properties * -SearchBase $fullbase |
    select personalTitle, msDS-PhoneticFirstName, msDS-PhoneticLastName, msDS-PhoneticDepartment, Title, mobile, telephoneNumber, facsimileTelephoneNumber, SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -Encoding Unicode C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\filename2.csv
```

```
Get-ADUser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following
partition(s): 'DC=domain,DC=com , CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com , 
CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com , DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com ,
DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=com'.
At C:\Scripts\ADUsers\export\ad-users_export-csv.ps1:21 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Server $adserver -LDAPFilter '(& (msExchMailboxGuid=*) (!sAMAccountN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the nested single quotes from your search base string: `"OU=Users,$oucity,$oubase,DC=domain,DC=com"`.

Comment: You also don't need quotes around the property names `$_.oubase` , `$_.oucity` or `$_.filename`

Comment: Ahhh, god, it was just these single quotes... thanks for that. Now in the exported CSV files, it is just full of `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`. Any Ideas?